# Scrapy - Pipe data to database if keyword match found

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Put simply, I'm scraping web data in Scrapy.

I need to analyse the scraped data for keywords / regex and if matched, pipeline the data to database. If not found, drop.

My question is: should/can I do this from within Scrapy and if so do you have any high level suggestions for me to research further.

Or should I simply perform this task outside of Scrapy.

Ideally I'd like to do it all from within Scrapy.

ps I'm new to Scrapy / Python and Stackoverflow and have researched this as far as possible and found no definitive answers/guidance.

Comment: This looks like a good fit for a custom Item Pipeline: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html. Item pipelines can be used to do post-processing tasks such as the one you mentioned.

Comment: I thought so, thank you. I'll point my research that way.